# Displaying image specific to NSString value

Tags: xcode, xcode4, nsstring, nsnumber

I'm trying to post a specific image if a specific value is called, and it is my understanding this is not working because NSNumber is not properly being converted to an NSString, but I am unsure if this is the problem. Through the use of NSLog, I see that the data is passing through, such as a rating of 4.5, in which case I would like to show four and a half stars, but the image does not post. I verified already that the view is linked up and everything is connected, but no dice. Code below. Feedback greatly appreciated!

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [self setString];

    NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *string1 = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *string2 = [[dic objectForKey:@"rating"]stringValue];

    NSLog(@"RATE STRING ---> %@", string2);

    if (string2 == @"0")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zerorate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"1")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"onerate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"1.5")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"onehalfrate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"2")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tworate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"2.5")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"twohalfrate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"3")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"threerate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"3.5")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"threehalfrate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"4")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fourrate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"4.5")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fourhalfrate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
    if (string2 == @"5")
    {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fiverate.png"];
        [imageView2 setImage:img];
    }
        [[self myTableView] reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value for `string2 == @"0"` is undefined.  Try `if ([string2 isEqualToString:@"0"])`.

Also, you might consider naming your png files after the value you're getting back.  Then you could just do:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:string2];
[imageView2 setImage:img];
```

If this doesn't resolve the issue, what happens when you `po string2` in the debugger?  What happens when you `po img` after it's set, and what happens when you `po imageView2`?

Comment: Ack! A common issue if I am not mistaken: "isEqualToString" vs "==" ....... I'm silly, I should have known "isEqualToString" might fix this! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @greg23af If you found the answer satisfactory, please mark it so by using the checkbox to the left.  (http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)

Comment: Also, you should update to the newest version of Xcode, which should  generate a warning for this.